# Django Form Wizard Dynamic Form Not Saving Data

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-formwizard

Currently Happening:

- Dynamically generated form and form fields are being displayed.
- Enter some data into the said fields, but `self.get_all_cleaned_data()` returns nothing.
- Form returns to page 0 instead of submitting the form and using `done()`

What I want to happen:
 - Data in fields to be retained and displayed when going back, or to the confirmation page
 - Form to actually submit and use `done()` to process and save

---

The following the my `forms.py`

```
class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        localized_fields = ('__all__',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields = kwargs.pop('fields')
        fields = self.fields
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not isinstance(fields, str):
            for i in fields.fields.all():
                widget = forms.TextInput()
                _type = forms.CharField

                if i.field_type == Field.TEXTAREA_FIELD:
                    widget = forms.Textarea
...
        self.fields[i.name] = _type(**fields)
```

This is supposed to get Database created forms and field data and generate fields accordingly. For example:

Form A has fields:

- Name (Regular Text Field)
- Address (Textarea)

The above code will then generate fields for those.

---

The next block of code is from my `views.py` file

```
FORM_TEMPLATES = {
    "0": 'order/details.html',
    "1": 'order/details.html',
    "2": 'order/details.html',
    "3": 'order/details.html',
    "4": 'order/details.html',
    "confirm": 'order/confirm.html',
}

class Order(SessionWizardView):
    form_list = [OrderForm]

    def get_current_step_form(self, company, *args, **kwargs):
        step_form = [Form.objects.all()]
        step_form.append('Confirm')
        return step_form

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(Order, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)            

        # Returns {}, but I want this to return all previous field values
        context.update({
            'all_data': self.get_all_cleaned_data(),
        })
       return context

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        go_to_step = self.request.POST.get('wizard_goto_step', None)
        form = self.get_form(data=self.request.POST)

        current_index = self.get_step_index(self.steps.current)
        goto_index = self.get_step_index(go_to_step)

        if current_index > goto_index:
            self.storage.set_step_data(self.steps.current,
                self.process_step(form))
            self.storage.set_step_files(self.steps.current,
                self.process_step_files(form))

        return super(Order, self).post(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        """
        Get the form and add to form_list
        """
        form = super(Order, self).get_form(step, data, files)
        company = ...
        get_forms = self.get_current_step_form(company=company)
        form_list_value = dict(self.form_list)['0']

        while len(self.form_list.items()) < len(get_forms):
            self.form_list.update({str(len(self.form_list.items())): form_list_value})

        return form


    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
       return HttpResponse("View")
```

`done()` is a work in progress, but it doesn't even seem to reach that point, as it keeps going from (for example) Form 0-1-2-3-0-...

The confirm form will not have any field values form the previous pages and will only return `{}`

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you still want to use django-formwizard? The last commit on GitHub is 7 years ago. Probably it is simply not compatible to recent Django versions. And don't even think about using an outdated version of Django

Comment: I couldn't use the formtools tag which is why I used the django-formwizard one